# php nested array to dictionary

Tags: php, arrays, object, dictionary

How can I get this:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => variation
        [value] => variation1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => variationid
        [value] => 70105
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => fullName
        [value] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => address
        [value] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => country
        [value] => usa
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => state
        [value] => Utah
    )
```

to look like this:

```
$fields['variation']=>variation1[variationid]=>70105.. etc
```

I tried:

```
foreach($_POST['fields'] as $key => $value){
    $fields[$key] = $value;
}
```

I thought this should work, but it gives it back to me looking the exact same way. This is just a serializedArray() from jquery passed into POST;  I basically just want to be able to access it using the $fields['variation'] accessing. But it's making it difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the nested array correctly, `$value` holds the array with `name` and `value` and since `$key` (0,1,...) is not needed, you don't even need to define it.

```
foreach ($_POST['fields'] as $data) {
    $fields[ $data['name'] ] = $data['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, and it seems obvious now that you show it. As a side comment, is it possible to make jQuery send the form data as a one level array into post, just as the browser would? Instead of having to fix it like this in php once you receive it?

Comment: That should be no problem but depends on how exactly you use jQuery to send a POST request

Comment: `<form class=myform>
 <input type=hidden name=variationid value=70105/>
 <input name=fullName value=myname/> etc..`

`$form = $('#myForm');
 $fields = $form.serializeArray();
 $.post("handler.php", "fields": $fields);`

Sorry i don't know how to put line breaks in... @kingkero

Comment: Ah ok, I honestly don't know if you can do this without ending up writing your own JS method. Research this topic and (if you didn't find a solution) ask another question on SO ;)